# Process each row to get date

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, rdd, apache-spark-dataset

I have a file having year and mon01,mon02

[image]

extract month using last two characters from columname(ie - 01 from MON01)
length of text value in the respective months(MON01,MON02..) is same as number of days in the month.
where retrive the date for every 1 occur.

like - 2018-01-02 (02 day because of 1 occur at 2nd day)
       2018-01-03
       2018-01-07

How can we do in spark-scala to get the result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    UDF:
    def myudf =(month:String,year:String ,value:String ) => {
        val month1 = month.replaceAll("[A-Za-z]+","")
        var date=1
        val dateList = ListBuffer[String]()
        for(char<-value){ 
          if(char=='1'){
           dateList += year+"-"+month1+"-"+date
          } else {
            dateList += ""
          }
          date += 1
        }
        dateList.filter(_.nonEmpty)
      }
    //Main Method
    val data = spark.read.option("header", "true").csv("data.csv")
    data.show()
    +----+-----+-----+
    |Year|Mon01|Mon02|
    +----+-----+-----+
    |2018|01110|00111|
    |2019|01100|00001|
    +----+-----+-----+
    val myCostumeudf = udf(myudf)
    val monthCols = data.columns.drop(1)
    val requiredDF = monthCols.foldLeft(data){
        case (df, month) =>
          df.withColumn("Date_"+month, myCostumeudf(lit(month),data("Year"),data(month)))
      }
    requiredDF.show(false)
    +----+-----+-----+---------------------------------+---------------------------------+
    |Year|Mon01|Mon02|Date_Mon01                       |Date_Mon02                       |
    +----+-----+-----+---------------------------------+---------------------------------+
    |2018|01110|00111|[2018-01-2, 2018-01-3, 2018-01-4]|[2018-02-3, 2018-02-4, 2018-02-5]|
    |2019|01100|00001|[2019-01-2, 2019-01-3]           |[2019-02-5]                      |
    +----+-----+-----+---------------------------------+---------------------------------+
```

I hope this will help you..

Comment: just a query, why used case?

Comment: No,without case also it will work. case is required if you are using any map.you can upvote if it helps you.

Answer (score -1):

1. get list columns

   val cols = df.columns.toList 
       val res = cols.foldLeft(...)

   `{  val filterDF = colWhere.foldLeft(pDYF){(tmpDF, colName) =>
       {
         val cn = s"${colName}_${colName}"
         val v: Option[String] = if (colName == "countries"
           || colName == "states"
           || colName == "zipCodes"
           || colName == "genders"
           || colName == "providers") {
           val vc = tmpDF.first().getAs[String](colName).asInstanceOf[mutable.WrappedArray[String]].map(x=>x).toArray
           val vc1: Option[String] = if(vc.length == 0) None else Some(vc.map(i=> s"$colName" + " = '" + i.toString + "'").mkString(" or "))
           vc1
         } else {
           val vc = tmpDF.first().getAs[Long](colName).asInstanceOf[mutable.WrappedArray[Long]].map(x=>x).toArray
           val vc1: Option[String] = if(vc.length == 0) None else Some(vc.map(i=> s"$colName" + " = " + i.toString).mkString(" or "))
           vc1
         }
     tmpDF.withColumn(cn, lit(v.getOrElse("")))
   }}}`

Comment: can you please tell in foldleft, how to process on particular column?

Comment: @mvasylin , can you post something relevant?

Comment: add exampl e with other task. you need substr month with col name. also you need value column month convert to List days month and save to new field